# How can I create statically typed, n dimensional arrays in python 2.7?

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, list-comprehension, labview

I am working on a python module that allows people to write python scripts for automation of labview test systems.  The idea is that the module will have methods to allow the user to get test input parameters from labview, do some math in python, send the parameters back to labview and run a test.

Labview uses statically typed data, and especially in arrays.  If data of a different type is written to a labview array, it will be coerced by labview into the static type of the array (e.g. you cannot write a float to an array of int32)

When python gets data from python (using labview's "flatten to xml"), the data is transmitted along with a list of dimension sizes (one size for each dimension, and its data type. Data MUST be returned with the same data type.  I would like to create data structures (dictionaries, lists, tuples) of those data types.  However, with python 2.7, if an array was a list (or a list of lists in the case of a multi-dimensional array), dynamic data typing will allow someone to, say, divide two integers and write a float value into the array that should be statically typed to integers.

Are there methods to:  1) raise an exception if a user's script tries to write the wrong data type?  or 2) have the program silently cast the value to the type of the data?  I think I would prefer to raise an exception.

I would like to know if there is some efficient and generalized method for creating statically typed multidimensional arrays which would either raise an exception or coerce the data to the desired type.

Another issue I am struggling with is how to dynamically create n dimensional arrays.  I was looking at list comprehensions but most of the examples, documentations, and stackoverflow answers only deal with 2 or three dimensions and known sizes.  in this case, I will have a list of dimension sizes with an unknown number of dimensions to start with.

As an example of what comes in from Labview, here is what a 2 dimensional array looks like in xml:

```
<Array>
 <Name>My2DArray</Name>
 <Dimsize>2</Dimsize>
 <Dimsize>2</Dimsize>
 <I32>
  <Name>Numeric</Name>
  <Val>-1</Val>
 </I32>
 <I32>
  <Name>Numeric</Name>
  <Val>1</Val>
 </I32>
 <I32>
  <Name>Numeric</Name>
  <Val>0</Val>
 </I32>
 <I32>
  <Name>Numeric</Name>
  <Val>3</Val>
 </I32>
</Array>
```

Here is what I have tried, it seems to work ok but may not be the best way of doing it.  If "node" is an etree document of the above XML:

```
import numpy as np
def XMLType_to_dType(XMLType):
    switch = {
        'Boolean' : np.dtype('b'),
        'String'  : np.dtype('S'),
        'i8' : np.dtype('i1'),      
        'I16': np.dtype('i2'),
        'I32': np.dtype('i4'), 
        'I64': np.dtype('i8'),
        'U8' : np.dtype('u1'),
        'U16': np.dtype('u2'),
        'U32': np.dtype('u4'),
        'U64': np.dtype('u8'),
        'SGL': np.dtype('f2'),
        'DBL': np.dtype('f4'),
        'EXT': np.dtype('f8'),
        'CSG': np.dtype('c2'),
        'CDB': np.dtype('c4'),
        'CXT': np.dtype('c8'),
    } 
    dType =switch.get(XMLType)
    assert (dType != None),'Error in XML_to_dType: unrecognized XMLType: {0}'.format(XMLType)
    return dType

def parseArray(node):
    dimSizes = []
    tempList = []
    created = False    # will be set to true when the array is created
    for ele in node:
        tag = ele.tag
        if tag == 'Name':
            name = ele.text
        elif tag == 'Dimsize':
            dimSizes.append(int(ele.text)) 
        else:                                   # after the <Name> and <Dimsize> elements, there should only be data remaining
            if created == False:                # the first data element
                XMLType = tag
                dType = XMLType_to_dType(XMLType)
                created = True
            assert (tag == XMLType),'XMLType: {0} does not equal Data Type: {1}'.format(XMLType, tag)  #They should all be the same type or there is an error
            for item in ele:
                if item.tag == 'Val':
                    tempList.append(item.text)                    

    tempArray = np.reshape(np.asarray(tempList,dtype=dType),tupledimSizes))    # build the numpy array here      
    return [name,tempArray]
```

Comment: Have you had look at numpy (numpy.org), yet?

Comment: the ``array`` module from the standard library may already be sufficient

Comment: What do numpy or the array module do to help?  Do they raise an error or coerse a value being written to an array?  Is this native behaviour for them or does something special need to be done?

Comment: I do not think you can use [tag:array] to create multi-dimensional arrays, is this correct?

Comment: A standard [array](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/array.html) raises `TypeError` if you try to assign a different data type to it, but as it stands is only one-dimensional. A numpy [array](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/user/quickstart.html#basic-operations) has multiple dimensions but allows coercion between data types. The answer is probably to write a class based on standard `array` that keeps track of dimensions, or one based on numpy `array` with a `set` method that traps incorrect data types.